# Layer 3D to Feature Class Empty Output

Tags: arcgis-10.0, 3d, arcscene

I'm trying to build 3D buildings from 2D footprints. I extrude by the building heights, and input the surface by editing the properties. From here I use the Layer 3D to Feature Class tool to convert to multipatch.

However the output from this results in a seemingly empty feature class, with no entries in the Attribute Table. I've tried saving the extruded buildings as a layer and using that as input to the Layer 3D to Feature Class tool, producing the same result of an empty feature class.

Am I missing something about this tool? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have also encountered the same problem. I imported a .3ds file to multipatch and my attributes table has only one entry. All buildings are on the same layer and I cannot make any edits. Has anyone any idea how to fix this?
Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, please take a [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Your answer did not provide a solution, add this as a comment to the original question.